# regex for parsing widget {widget.option1.option2.optionN}

Tags: php, regex

I have string like this

```
{widget-123-abc.option1.option2.optionN}
```

my regex : `/widget-([0-9]{3})-([a-z|A-Z]{3})(.*)}/g`

result my regex :

```
$a = array(
  [0] => widget-123-abc.option1.option2.optionN},
  [1] => 123,
  [2] => abc,
  [3] => .option1.option2.optionN
)
```

result what i want is :

```
$b = array(
  [0] => widget-123-abc.option1.option2.optionN},
  [1] => 123,
  [2] => abc,
  [3] => option1,
  [4] => option2,
  [..(N)] => option..(N),
)
```

is there any way without `explode('.', $a[3]);`

is there any regex pattern i can use?
thx before

Comment: yes, you can use instead (.*) something like this: ([.a-zA-Z0-9])+

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instead of implode you should use

```
explode('.', $a[3]);
```

Comment: sorry implode edited to explode. what i want is regex pattern

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use something like this:

Instead greed-dot: `(.+)`

you should use: `([.a-zA-Z0-9])+`

Comment: if i use this [code]([.a-zA-Z0-9])+[code]
result become :
$a = array(
  [0] => widget-123-abc.option1.option2.optionN},
  [1] => 123,
  [2] => abc,
  [3] => N
)